# DatePickerDialog listener

Tags: android, listener, android-datepicker

I am making an Android app where I use a `DatePickerDialog`. The intended function is for the user to select a date in the dialog, and then for a `TextView` to reflect that chosen date. However, I can't find any sort of a click listener to notify my Activity when the user has selected a date. I am looking for a way to detect when the user has selected a date, but from my main Activity. This is my `DatePickerDialog` class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private GregorianCalendar date;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
}

public GregorianCalendar getDate() {
    return date;
}
}
```

And the code where I launch the dialog:

```
DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

I currently launch the dialog from a class that extends `Activity`, and I am looking for a way to detect from within that class if a user has selected a date from the dialog. Any suggestions?

Comment: This will possible by just define a public function

Comment: If your changed date is gonna be pasted on the textview then you should simply override `onTextChanged` to check if the date is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading: [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

`Activity` has to implement `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    ...

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // the user selected, now you can do whatever you want with it
    }
}
```

`Activity` will be notified when user selected date if you add following code to `DialogPickerFragment` class:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mListener, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (!(context instanceof DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mListener = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small note: onAttach(Activity activity) is deprecated now, it's better to use onAttach(Context context)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way..

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if (this.mDateSetListener != null) {
        this.mDateSetListener.onDateSet(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}

public void setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener dateSetListener) {
    this.mDateSetListener = dateSetListener;
}

public interface OnDateSetListener {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
}

}
```

In your activity do this..

```
implement MyDialogFragment.OnDateSetListener;

MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            myDialogFragment.setOnDateSetListener(this);

@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       //Here is your data..
    }
```